# Show User Control through Static Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have been researching this, but haven't been able to find anything so far.

Currently, I am using a Javascript alert box on my ASP page:

```
public static class Alert
{
    public static void Show(string message)
    {
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + message + "');</script>";
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

        if (!page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("alert"))
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Alert), "alert", script);
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to call this from code behind by: `Alert.Show("Text");`

My plan is to replace the Javascript alert by utilizing the AjaxControlToolkit's ModalPopupExtender.  I am creating a user control that looks something like this:

```
            <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpAlert" runat="server" PopupControlID="" 
                TargetControlID="btnExport"  OkControlID="btnOK">
            </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSteps" runat="server" BackColor="#C5D9FC"  Width="10%"
            BorderColor="#093E9A" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="5px"
            style="border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;">
                                <div>
                <asp:Literal ID="lSteps" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div>
                <input id="btnOK" type="button" value="OK" />
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
```

I am wondering if there is a way I can create a static method to show this from codebehind, similar to how I used the Javascript alert.  I'd like to be able to wrap this in a class so I could just call AjaxAlert.Show(), without having to call anything in the aspx file.
This is still a rough idea, so if any more details are needed, just let me know.

Comment: You can show the `ModalPopupExtender` from codebehind. Therefore you need an invisible trigger button. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826141/display-in-correct-order-using-requiredfieldvalidators-validatorcallout-and-a-m

Comment: Thank you for this.  This was much easier than I realized.  Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as Accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the `ModalPopupExtender` from codebehind. Therefore you need an [invisible trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826141/display-in-correct-order-using-requiredfieldvalidators-validatorcallout-and-a-m) button.

```
mpAlert.Show();
```

So set the `TargetControlID` of the `ModalPopupExtender` to a hidden button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Hid_ShowDialog" Style="display: none" runat="server" />
```